# breaking from a program running in an interactive session in a screen window

Tags: gnu-screen, r

I am launching `R` (an interactive program) in a `screen` window in a remote session:

```
ssh me@..
screen -S R_ProjectName
R
```

In the R session, I would like to `break` execution.  Normally, this would be via <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

However, the command is getting submitted to `screen` instead of to `R`. 
What is the correct way to break in a program inside a screen window?

To clarify, I am not looking to kill the `R` process.  Rather, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> would be used to manually break out of (eg) a `for` loop.

---

I am working in iTerm2 on a Mac OS X connecting to Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: I've never had a problem using ctrl+C to break an app, even when running within screen (I'm almost always running in screen, or tmux). Are you sure this problem is "screen" related?

Comment: @GregHewgill, truthfully, no I am not sure.  What I am sure is that I hit `ctrl+c` and my R session continues running (evidenced by the file system, etc) but I am no longer actively in that window.

Comment: That should work: screen receives your Ctrl+C keystroke but passes it to the terminal where R is running. Does it work if you don't run screen?

Comment: @Gilles, yep, if I do *not* run `screen` (but still `ssh` to remote), `ctrl+c` works as normal

Answer (score 1):

To get out of `R` you typically use the command `q()` to quit a running instance.

#### Example

Run R.

```
$ R
```

Sitting at an R prompt:

```
R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

[Previously saved workspace restored]

>
```

Now exit:

```
> q()
Save workspace image? [y/n/c]: n
$
```

#### Breaking a running R command

If you've run something in `R` and want to abort it, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> is usually the way to accomplish this. If this doesn't work you might want to try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>.

If neither of the above work, you might have luck trying to send a signal to the running `R` process.

```
$ kill -USR1 <pid of R>
-or-
$ pkill -USR1 R
```

The 2nd form will kill all the running `R` processes, but saves you on having to look up the PID.

#### References

- [How to stop a running R command in linux other than ctrl+c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337825/how-to-stop-a-running-r-command-in-linux-other-than-ctrlc)

Answer (score -1):

You can get a process id by running `ps -A | grep R` and then `kill pid`.

Comment: To clarify, I am not looking to kill the process. I am looking to manually break out of, say, a for loop

Comment: If you break from a for loop in R, does that not also kill the process or is it an interactive shell?

Comment: it's interactive.  Similar to python

Comment: I haven't been able to find a good solution. Have you tried tmux? Does most everything screen does but can be a little nicer for interactive shells inside of tmux sessions. Learning curve is a little steep though.